# Laravel, many-to-many relationship to multiple models

Tags: php, laravel, many-to-many, pivot, relation

Looking for a simple way of doing the following in Laravel 5.

Imagine these models and interface

- Competition
- User
- Team
- Participant (Interface which User and Team implements)

A competition will have a many-to-many relationship to is participants, which can be either users or teams. So I need the competition_participant pivot table to have the following columns to define the models

- competition_id
- participant_id
- participant_type

But how do I write a relation on the Competition model, so it knows which model it should fetch from the database, and at the same time return a collection of mixed models or of the Interface type?

Comment: What you want is a polymorphic relation https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations

Comment: @fabio-antunes It is not quite the solution I am looking for. This would have me have both a _teams_ and a _users_ relation on my _Competition_ model, I am looking for a solution where I only have the _participants_ relation on my _Competition_ model which gives me the mixed instances of my _Participant_ interface.

Comment: No, on your Competition model you only have one relation named particapable, for example, and in your User model a relation to competition and in your Team also a relation to competition. Believe me , this is what you want just read the documentation

Comment: @fabio-antunes Thanks for your input, I actually tried the implementation from the documentation, but this will not achieve a many-to-many relation. I need my _users_ and _teams_ to be able to be in multiple competitions. It may be my stuborn brain that is keeping from the solution, maybe you could provide an example of how you would solve the problem?

Comment: I might have misunderstood your question. But can't you just declare two many to many relations on your competition (user & team) and write a getter that merges both collections?

Comment: @fester that would indeed work, however I would lose the nice api to attach and detach _users_ and _teams_ from the _competitions_ but it might be the solution, and then I could write a nice api that makes it more of a seemless integration.

Comment: @NikolajBoelJensen the proper way to do this is probably by using a polymorphic relationship though, I just wanted to suggest an alternative

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You had some confusions about which tables should get which columns.

Your participants table needs to be a table for managing the polymorphic relations of `users` and `teams`.  It receives a `particpatable_id` and `particpatable_type` as well as an `id` and `timestamps()` at the very minimum.

Then you need an additional table called `competition_participant` which will manage the belongs to many between `competitions` and your polymorphic table `participants`.

This will allow you to relate your `participants` to your `competitions`.  This way, you can grab all participants by a competition, call the `$participant->participatable` attribute on it which would return either an `App\User` or an `App\Team` depending on what type the participant is.

This is all tested.

### Migrations

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('competitions', function(Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->timestamps();
    });

    Schema::create('teams', function(Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->timestamps();
    });

    Schema::create('participants', function(Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('participatable_id');
        $table->string('participatable_type');
        $table->timestamps();
    });

    Schema::create('competition_participant', function(Blueprint $table) {
        $table->integer('competition_id');
        $table->integer('participant_id');
    });
}
```

### Models

```
class Competition extends Model
{
    public function participants()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Participant::class);
    }
}

class Participant extends Model
{
    public function participatable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }

    public function competitions()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Competition::class);
    }
}

class Team extends Model
{
    public function participants()
    {
        return $this->morphMany(Participant::class, 'participatable');
    }
}

class User extends Authenticatable
{

    public function participants()
    {
        return $this->morphMany(Participant::class, 'participatable');
    }

}
```

### Seeds

```
public function run()
{
    $faker = Faker\Factory::create();

    // Seed Users Table
    DB::table('users')->delete();

    $users = [];
    for($i = 0; $i < 100; $i++) {
        $users[] = [
            'name' => $faker->name,
            'email' => $faker->email,
            'password' => Hash::make($faker->password),
            'created_at' => new DateTime,
            'updated_at' => new DateTime
        ];
    }
    DB::table('users')->insert($users);


    // Seed Teams Table
    DB::table('teams')->delete();
    $teams = [];
    for($i = 0; $i < 20; $i++) {
        $teams[] = [
            'name' => 'Team ' . ucwords($faker->domainWord),
            'created_at' => new DateTime,
            'updated_at' => new DateTime
        ];
    }
    DB::table('teams')->insert($teams);


    // Seed Participants Table
    DB::table('participants')->delete();

    // Insert some of our users as participants
    $users = App\User::limit(20)->orderByRaw('rand()')->get();
    foreach($users as $user) {
        $user->participants()->create([]);
    }

    // Insert some of the teams as participants
    $teams = App\Team::limit(10)->orderByRaw('rand()')->get();
    foreach($teams as $team) {
        $team->participants()->create([]);
    }

    // Seed Competitions Table
    DB::table('competitions')->delete();

    $competitions = [];

    for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
        $competitions[] = [
            'name' => $faker->company,
            'created_at' => new DateTime,
            'updated_at' => new DateTime,
        ];
    }

    DB::table('competitions')->insert($competitions);


    // Seed Competitions Participants Relationships
    DB::table('competition_participant')->delete();

    // Sign up each participant to 3 random competitions
    $participants = App\Participant::all();
    $competitions = App\Competition::all();

    foreach($participants as $participant) {
        $participant->competitions()->sync($competitions->shuffle()->take(3));
    }
}
```

### Usage

```
    $competition = App\Competition::with('participants')->has('participants')->first();

    foreach($competition->participants as $participant) {
        echo get_class($participant->participatable); // Will output either App\User or App\Team
        echo "<br />";
    }
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. The extra table for participants solves my problem perfectly, don't know why I didn't think of that solution, must have been a really slow Friday for my brain ;) Thank you for the input, this put me back on track.

Answer (score 2):

This is just a copy paste from the [Laravel documentation about many to many polymorphic relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-polymorphic-relations).

To help you understand better this is the mapping between your models and the models that are on the Laravel documentation:

```
users == posts

teams == videos

competitions == tags

competitionables == tags
```

This how you should implement your polymorphic relationship, remember whenever you feel confused just look at the documentation and the mapping between your models and the documention models:

**Tables:**

```
users
    id - integer
    name - string

teams
    id - integer
    name - string

competitions
    id - integer
    name - string

competitionables
    competition_id - integer
    competitionable_id - integer
    competitionable_type - string
```

**Model Structure**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get all of the Competition for the user.
     */
    public function competitions()
    {
        return $this->morphToMany('App\Competition', 'competitionable');
    }
}

<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Team extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get all of the Competition for the Team.
     */
    public function competitions()
    {
        return $this->morphToMany('App\Competition', 'competitionable');
    }
}

<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Competition extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get all of the users that are assigned to this Competition.
     */
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->morphedByMany('App\User', 'competitionable');
    }

    /**
     * Get all of the Teams that are assigned to this Competition.
     */
    public function teams()
    {
        return $this->morphedByMany('App\Video', 'competitionable');
    }
}
```

**Retrieving The Relationship**

```
$user = App\User::find(1);

foreach ($user->competitions as $competition) {
    //
}
```

or the other way

```
$competition = App\Competition::find(1);

foreach ($competition->users as $user) {
    // do something with your users
}

foreach ($competition->teams as $team) {
    // do something with your teams
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the example, but this still gives me two collections on my _competition_, one for _users_ and one for _teams. What I want is a single collection of _participants_ which can hold both _users_ and _teams_